# Right triangular pyramid

Tags: geometry

I am somehow confused with this problem. It is said that this is a right triangular pyramid, but it has an equilateral triangle base? I am confused. How can I find VA?

It doesn't look like it has any 90 degrees angle though?

All I can found is that from C to AB is $5\sqrt{3}$

Dont worry about the rest, I will do it myself

I just need some explanation where is the 90 degrees should be. Thank you[image]

Comment: you can take the phrase "right triangular pyramid" to mean that the vertex $V$ is vertically above the centre of the base triangle

Comment: From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(geometry)): "A **right pyramid** has its apex directly above the centroid of its base." The adjective "right" in your question refers to the pyramid, not to the triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(geometry)) will clarify your problem:

> A **right pyramid** has its apex directly above the centroid of its base. Nonright pyramids are called **oblique pyramids**. A regular pyramid has a regular polygon base and is usually implied to be a right pyramid

[image]