# Right triangular pyramid angle

Tags: geometry

I am trying to find alpha and beta in this problem. Intuitively, alpha and beta should be the same right? But why I got a different result? Did I do something wrong?[image]

Me myself got alpha for 48.6 degrees and beta for 49.7 degrees. I find them after some long long calculation. Am I wrong or is it just because I rounded some decimals so I got a different answer?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Related but different: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4256191/right-triangular-pyramid

Comment: No this one is different. I only need explanation for the last question. I think they should be the same. Is there any error in my calculation or is it because the approximation?

Comment: @DavidK Why though? isn't it should be the same?

Comment: @Kadal Your calculations look correct to me. Good job. You should not be surprised, the angle between the planes is not the same as the angle  between some line on a plane and the other plane.

Answer (score 1):

The angles **should** be different. You would only get the same angle if $MB$ were perpendicular to the line of intersection of the two planes.